# How to create your own Function for Async operation in c++ UWP?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, uwp

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps), All the examples are using Windows's own function for Async operation.
Is it not possible to create you own Async function?

For example

```
//MainPage.xaml.h
int summation(int start_num, int stop_num);

//MainPage.xaml.cpp
int test_thread::MainPage::summation(int start_num, int stop_num)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (start_num; start_num <= stop_num; start_num++) sum += start_num;
    return sum;
}
```

And Call it like this,

```
IAsyncOperation<int> sum = summation(1, 10000000000);//error
auto sumTask = Concurrency::create_task(sum);
sumTask.then(/*...*/);
```

I also Tried to define the function as

```
//MainPage.xaml.h
IAsyncOperation<int>^ summer(int start_num, int stop_num);
```

But got this error **cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone**

Comment: You should be able to use lambdas, like: `create_task([]() -> int { return summation(1, 100000);  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    auto workItem = ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler([this, a, b](IAsyncAction^ workItem)
    {
        Platform::String ^ updateString = (a+b).ToString();

        //UI update
        Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(
            Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::High,
            ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, updateString]()
        {
            textBlock->Text = updateString;
        }));
        //END UI upate
    });

    auto asyncAction = Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(workItem);
```

Or this

```
    int inputPrime = platformSting2Int(textBox_primeCheck->Text);
    std::shared_ptr<bool> isItPrime = std::make_shared<bool>(true);

    auto workItem = ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler([this, inputPrime, isItPrime](IAsyncAction^ workItem)
    {
        *isItPrime = IsPrime(inputPrime);//IsPrime() is my custom function
    });

    auto asyncAction = Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(workItem);

    asyncAction->Completed = ref new Windows::Foundation::AsyncActionCompletedHandler([this, isItPrime](IAsyncAction^ asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
    {
        if (asyncStatus == AsyncStatus::Canceled) return;

        Platform::String ^ updateString = "is not prime.";
        if(*isItPrime) updateString = "is prime.";

        //UI update
        Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(
            Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::High,
            ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this, updateString]()
        {
            textBlock_primeCheckResult->Text = updateString;
        }));
        //END UI upate
    });
```